# Calling a class which written in file .hpp make error "Exception thrown: read access violation. this->p was nullptr."

Tags: c++, class, opencv

I am writting a class in file .hpp and i am using VS2019 and opencv 3.4.1.
It return this error:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->p was nullptr. at line 1419 of file mat.inl.hpp
```

When I compile only that .hpp file, it succeeds without error, but if I try to declare this class in another file it will return this error:

[Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91thB.png)

This is how my file .hpp look like

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Header_1.h"

class GUI_1
{
private:
    //Create a black image 
    Mat imgBlank = Mat::zeros(original.size(), CV_8UC3);

    //Take size original to 2 part
    int height = original.size().height;
    int width = original.size().width;

public:
    //Sources img (input)
    Mat original;

    //extension coordinate variable for tracking object
    int posX;
    int posY;
    //last line of  input
    
    //color for cross hair and coordinate
    double red = 0;
    double green = 255;
    double blue = 255;


    //function
    Mat crosshair()
    {
        // Crate blank img
        Mat img = imgBlank;

        //properties
        int length = 10;
        
        //draw crosshair
        //horizon
        line(img, Point(posX - length, posY), Point(posX + length, posY), Scalar(blue, green, red), 1);

        //vertical
        line(img, Point(posX, posY - length), Point(posX, posY + length), Scalar(blue, green, red), 1);

        return img;
    }

    Mat imgCoordinate()
    {
        //blank img
        Mat img = imgBlank;

        //coordinate of text with object
        const int subX = 2;
        const int subY =2;

        //put coordinate

        string Text = "X=" + to_string(posX) + "Y=" + to_string(posY);
        putText(img, Text, Point(posX + subX, posY + subY), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, Scalar(blue, green, red), 1);

        return img;
    }

    //Create imgGUI for show (output)
    Mat imgGUI = imgBlank + crosshair() + imgCoordinate();

};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code which has the same issue:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MatSize {
    int value = 42;
    int operator()(){ return value; }
};

struct Mat {
    MatSize size;
};

struct Foo {
    int x = m.size();
    Mat m;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Foo f;
    std::cout << f.x;
}
```

[Possible output is](https://godbolt.org/z/YTWzWWs4s) `0`. Though it could print anything else, because the code has undefined behavior. Members are initialized in the order they are listed in the class definition. Hence, `x = m.size();` reads from an uninitialized `MatSize::value`. In a debug build, there might be some safety nets that produce the runtime error when you call `MatSize::operator()` on a not yet initilaized instance.

Be careful with order of initalization. This is ok:

```
struct Foo {
    Mat m;
    int x = m.size();
};
```